# Enable user login, there by login can happen either as root or user based on requirement

Tags: shell-script, login, embedded, useradd

I am working with a board and when it finishes the boot, it gives us login as root user. What I want to do is to login as user or root based my requirement. Mean when the board boots up i should get a prompt which allows me to login as either root or login as user.
How can i go about this.

```
# Startup the system
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -o remount,rw /
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -t proc proc /proc
null::sysinit:/bin/mkdir /mnt/jffs2
null::sysinit:/bin/sh /scripts/mtd_mknod
null::sysinit:/bin/sh /scripts/mount_data_partition
null::sysinit:/bin/mount -a
null::sysinit:/bin/echo "/sbin/hotplug" > /sys/kernel/uevent_helper
# now run init.non-volatile.rcS script
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/init.non-volatile.rcS
null::sysinit:/bin/hostname -F /etc/hostname
null::sysinit:/sbin/ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 up
null::sysinit:/sbin/route add -net 127.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 lo 
# Ruby inbuilt kernel profiler
null::sysinit:/bin/mknod /dev/profiler c 10 149
# now run any rc scripts
::sysinit:/etc/init.d/rcS

# Ruby patch - run a shell on the serial console
console::respawn:/bin/sh -l

# Logging junk
null::sysinit:/bin/touch /var/log/messages
null::respawn:/sbin/syslogd -n -i eth1_0 -L -m 0
null::respawn:/sbin/klogd -n
#tty3::respawn:/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your user and `root` have passwords; as root, run:

```
passwd user
passwd
```

(replacing `user` as appropriate). Once you've done that, you can replace

```
console::respawn:/bin/sh -l
```

which starts a shell directly, with

```
console::respawn:/bin/login
```

if you have `/bin/login` on your system.

Traditionally you'd use `getty` to manage the serial connection completely, something like

```
console::respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 console
```

(I'm not sure those are the appropriate options for your setup.)

**Before you embark on all this**, make sure you have a way of restoring the old way of starting a shell, or logging in over the network, to avoid locking yourself out of the system if something goes wrong...

Comment: If i type passwd user i get an  error message passwd: unknown user user... Can you please tell how to go about this ?

Comment: What error message?

Comment: passwd: unknown user user

Comment: You need to use the appropriate username, `user` is just a placeholder in my example (hence "replacing `user` as appropriate").

Comment: In my board there is no adduser utility...so should i add this utility and go about the changes that you have suggested ?

Comment: You could add a user manually, but it's probably easier to add `adduser`; so yes, add `adduser` and implement the rest of my suggestions.